# Can I detect whether an object has called GC.SuppressFinalize?

Tags: c#, .net, finalizer

Is there a way to detect whether or not an object has called GC.SuppressFinalize?

I have an object that looks something like this (full-blown Dispose pattern elided for clarity):

```
public class ResourceWrapper {
    private readonly bool _ownsResource;
    private readonly UnmanagedResource _resource;

    public ResourceWrapper(UnmanagedResource resource, bool ownsResource) {
        _resource = resource;
        _ownsResource = ownsResource;
        if (!ownsResource)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ~ResourceWrapper() {
        if (_ownsResource)
            // clean up the unmanaged resource
    }
}
```

If the `ownsResource` constructor parameter is `false`, then the finalizer will have nothing to do -- so it seems reasonable (if a bit quirky) to call `GC.SuppressFinalize` right from the constructor. However, because this behavior is quirky, I'm very tempted to note it in an XML doc comment... and if I'm tempted to comment it, then I ought to write a unit test for it.

But while [System.GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.aspx) has methods to *set* an object's finalizability ([SuppressFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx), [ReRegisterForFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.reregisterforfinalize.aspx)), I don't see any methods to *get* an object's finalizability. Is there any way to query whether GC.SuppressFinalize has been called on a given instance, short of buying Typemock or writing my own CLR host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to confirm that finalization has been suppressed if your object doesn't own the resource, perhaps you could have the finalizer assert that it owns the resource?  The test would have to do GC.Collect and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers, but production code wouldn't have anything extra except the assert (which could be omitted from the production build).  One slight caveat with the assert: if the thread that creates the object dies between creating the object and setting the ownership status, the finalizer may run inappropriately.

That having been said, I wonder whether it would be better to have an abstract ResourceWrapper type, with separate subtypes OwnedResourceWrapper and SharedResourceWrapper, that own or do not own the resource in question.  Then the subtype that doesn't own resources wouldn't need to have a finalizer in the first place.  Note that it may be useful for SharedResourceWrapper to implement IDisposable as a no-op.

Comment: Both good ideas, but I like the second: move the "owner" responsibility to a separate object.

Comment: Using a separate object type is IMHO apt to be cleaner when it works (i.e. the wrapper knows when it's created whether the resource will be owned, and that status will never change) but it may require a little more code.  It's certainly useful to have both techniques available.  As noted in the edit above, finalizers default to running before it's established there will be anything for them to do; that seems a bit sloppy, but probably won't be a problem in most scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, the GC just doesn't provide this information.  Good reason for that, it isn't just two states that the object can be in.  It also might already be on the finalization queue or it might already have been finalized.

A custom CLR host isn't going to help you with that, the hosting interface don't provide any hooks into the gc.  You can check if SuppressFinalize has been called when it should have simply by checking this in the finalizer.  Log it (quickly).  You can't prove the opposite.

Fwiw, the .NET frame classes don't do this, they just let the finalizer run anyway.

Comment: Some BCL classes actually do SuppressFinalize from their constructors, e.g. SqlConnection (though I haven't seen any that do it conditionally).

Answer (score 2):

This may help (reductio absurdum). A trick would be do some log (this could be a static state) in finalizers and if somebody is absent, he has called the suppress finalize but still you cannot be sure when.

This is working if you are the author of the type.

Comment: I thought about that. That would also require calling GC.Collect and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers from my test, though that's doable. But I hate making production code do extra work that's only for testing.

Comment: I don't recommend it at all, but still a solution. Maybe you find a more reliable solution from others.